# How to stop daemon thread or kill process?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-daemon

I have this code which I want to be run in the background.

```
context.t = threading.Thread(target=psubscribe, args=[context, paramA, paramB, paramC], daemon=True)
context.t.start()
```

this is normal psubscribe to redis results are some kind of notyfications

```
def psubscribe(context, paramA, paramB, paramC):
    context.test_config = load_config()
    RedisConnector(context.test_config["redis_h"],
               context.test_config["redis_db_"])
    redis_subscriber_connector = RedisConnector(context.test_config["subscriber_redis_h"],
                                                         int(paramC),
                                                         int(context.test_config[
                                                                 "subscriber_redis_p"]))
context.redis_connectors = redis_notification_subscribe.psubscribe_to_redis_event(paramA,
                                                                                             timeout_seconds=int(
                                                                                             paramB))
```

But this psubscribe is throwing the results one time per step so actually 2 result and I need only one.
How can I stop daemon sending psubscribe ?